# Ionic React Controllers(Framework delegate issue while using Controllers)

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic5

WHen i try to use the modalController in ionic core, i get `Uncaught (in promise) Error: framework delegate is missing`.

```
modalController
 .create({
   keyboardClose: true,
   component: ImagePreview,
   backdropDismiss: true, 
   swipeToClose: true, 
   // What does this Property does and how do i use it, i think the modalCtrl require this in Ionic-React
   delegate: 
   })
   .then((tost) => tost.present());
```

Comment: Same issue. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

that is not how you create modals in react - https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal

```
<IonModal
  isOpen={showModal}
  keyboardClose ={true}
  backdropDismiss ={true}
  swipeToClose={true}
  onDidDismiss={() => setShowModal(false)}>
  <ImagePreview />
</IonModal>
```